# Laravel 9 - Display Name Instead of ID in View

Tags: laravel

***SOLVED***

As the title says, I'm struggling to get the field name to show instead of the ID.
I'm new to Laravel and PHP and only started using Laravel 2 months ago.  I have looked through the answered threads but still not coming right.

I have 2 tables *members* (club members) and *teams* (soccer teams).
Obviously a member can only belong to one team and a team can have many members.

**My DB tables:**
[Members Table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI8ci.png)
[Teams Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfrOg.png)

**My Migrations:**

Members Migration

```
Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('member_image')->nullable();
        $table->string('member_first_name');
        $table->string('member_last_name');
        $table->string('member_type')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('team_id');
        $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('teams');
        $table->timestamps();
```

Table Migration

```
Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('team_name');
        $table->string('team_coach')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
```

**My Models**

Member: *App\Models\Backend\Member*

```
protected $table = 'members';

protected $fillable = [
    'member_image',
    'member_first_name',
    'member_last_name',
    'member_type',
    'team_id',
    'member_safa',
    'member_email',
    'member_phone',
    'member_id_number',
    'member_subs'
];

public function team(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'team_id', 'id');
}
```

Team: *App\Models\Backend\Member*

```
protected $table = 'teams';

protected $fillable = [
    'team_name',
    'team_coach'
];

public function member(){
    return $this->hasMany(Member::class );
}
```

**My Controllers:**

Member:

```
use App\Models\Backend\Team;
use App\Models\Backend\Member;

class MembersController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $members = Member::orderBy('member_last_name')->get();
            return view('backend.members.index')
                ->with('members', $members);
    
        }
```

**My View:**

```
  @foreach ($members as $key => $member)
    <tr>
      ...
      <td>{{ $member->team_id }}</td>
  @endforeach
```

And finally how it displays when viewing page
[display on view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMbg0.png)

I'm sure it is something simple I haven't done.

*Edit: Solved - In my view I had to change

```
<td>{{ $member->team_id }}</td>
```

to

```
<td>{{ $member->team->team_name }}</td>
```

Comment: have you tried $member->team->team_name or something?

Comment: In controller, you assigned $members twice with different value. Is that typo or intentional?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth that was a typo, I will edit my post.

Comment: omg, @Mr.Kenneth '$member->team->team_name' worked.  I knew it was something stupid I didn't do correctly.  Thank you so much :)

Comment: Added an answer in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this: `$member->team->team_name` if eager loading is properly set.

Comment: I have a new problem now, works fine until I add a member that isn't associated with a team (Social Member)

The Error: 'Attempt to read property "team_name" on null'

Comment: If you wish to assign blank, you can either `$member->team->team_name ?? null` or `isset($member->team) ? $member->team->team_name : null`. Or something.

Comment: Basically, you tell blade to assign blank if name is null.